# Mettler toledo IND780 read weight through javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, internet-explorer, serial-port, activexobject

How one can communicate with Mettler toledo IND780 device for reading weight through browser application through javascript. I know ActiveXObject will work with only Internet explorer . But is there any documentation or API to do this via javascript.

Comment: What do your web searches for an API tell you?

Comment: browsers don't generally have access to devices on the computer itself, apart from certain defined APIs (e.g. to access a camera, or provide the location). You won't get access to some random device which isn't compliant with one of those built-in APIs. You _might_ be able to do it by writing an extension for the browser, I don't know much about browser extensions to be honest - so there's a research topic for you to go and find out, unless someone else here knows about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You need to contact the developers of the **Mettler toledo IND780** device and confirm with them, whether this product can interact with any Web application or not. As other community member already informed you that this kind of devices can not be accessible from any web app.

I try to visit their site and I find that this product can work like below.

[image]

Reference:

[IND780 Advanced Weighing Terminal](https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/products/Industrial_Weighing_Solutions/Terminals-and-Controllers/terminals-bench-floor-scales/advanced-bench-floor-applications/IND780.html)

They can give you the proper idea or any example to interact with this device.

If they deny you that this device cannot work with Web app then try to store the data from that device to any Excel file and then try to import the data from that Excel file to your web app may help you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but maybe this answer can help someone, best way around is to code a back-end application to get the data you need from the Shared Data of the IND780 (Shared Data Reference manual), example in Python3:

```
            import socket
            import time

            # Create a TCP/IP socket
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            # Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
            server_address = ('172.16.40.98', 1701)
            print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
            sock.connect(server_address)

            try:

                time.sleep(0.1)
                data = sock.recv(2048)
                print('1 received {!r}'.format(data))

                message = b'user admin\n'
                print('2 sending {!r}'.format(message))
                sock.sendall(message)
                
                data = sock.recv(2048)
                print('3 received {!r}'.format(data)) 
                print(len(message))

                print('')

                message = b'read wt0101\n'
                # wt--01 Displayed Gross Weight
                
                print('4 sending {!r}'.format(message))
                sock.sendall(message)
                
                data = sock.recv(2048)
                print('5 received {!r}'.format(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a TelNet client to communicate with the device. Currently i'm using C# to connect and read information. I think you can use a similar library from JavaScript side.

Comment: The question asked for browser based as opposed to TelNet client answers.